# Django raise forms ValidationError not working

Tags: python, django, django-forms, django-templates

This could be a repeated question, however I did not found a solution for my issue.
Issue is with my UserLoginForm validation. "raise forms.ValidationError" is not working and not throwing error. Everything else is perfectly working.

My Form validation block

```
    def clean(self):
        cleanedData= super(UserLoginForm, self).clean()
        username= cleanedData.get('username')
        password = cleanedData.get('password')

        if User.objects.filter(username=username).exists() is False:
            print("User not available Validation should trigger")
            raise forms.ValidationError('User does not exists.')
        else:
            user = authenticate(username=username, password=password)
            if user is None:
                print("Authentication Failed Validation should trigger")
                raise forms.ValidationError('Invalid Credentials.')
```

Views.py

```
def signin(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form= UserLoginForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            username= str(form.cleaned_data['username']).lower()
            password= form.cleaned_data['password']

            user= authenticate(username= username, password= password)
            if user:
                if user.is_active:
                    login(request, user)
                    return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse_lazy('testapp:index'))
                else:
                    return HttpResponse('User Not Active')
            else:
                return HttpResponse('Login Unsuccessful.')
        else:
            return HttpResponse('Form not valid')
    elif request.method == 'GET':
        if request.user.is_authenticated:
            return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse_lazy('testapp:index'))
        else:
            form= UserLoginForm()
    return render(request, 'signin.html', {'form': form})
```

HTML Temlplate

```
{% extends "base.html" %}
{% load static %}
{% block bodyblock %}
    <div class="container">
        <img src="{% static "images/face.png" %}" alt="image no found">
        <div class="heading">
            <h1>Login</h1>
        </div>
        <form action="" method="post" id="signinForm">
            {% csrf_token %}
            <div class="form-input">
                <i class="fas fa-user"></i>
                {{ form.username }}
            </div>
            {% if form.username.errors %}
                <span>{{ form.username.errors }}</span>
            {% endif %}
            <div class="form-input">
                <i class="fas fa-lock"></i>
                {{ form.password }}
            </div>
            {% if form.password.errors %}
                <span>{{ form.password.errors }}</span>
            {% endif %}

            {{ form.non_field_errors }}
            {{ form.source.errors }}
            {{ form.source }}

            <div class="form-submit">
                <input type="submit" value="Sign In">
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>
{% endblock bodyblock %}
```

To catch errors I am using all 3 ({{ form.non_field_errors }}, {{ form.source.errors }}, {{ form.source }}) in my HTML template.

I am able to see "User not available Validation should trigger" and "Authentication Failed Validation should trigger", but raise VailidationError not working.

Comment: Please show the view.

Comment: @Daniel Roseman Added the view

Comment: But you never render the template again after posting. So where are you expecting those errors to be displayed?

Comment: Added HTML Template, could you please suggest how and where should i render the error. I am already using same structure in registration page, its working for for that block but not for login block.

Comment: @KartikPunde for which field in form do you want add validations

Comment: The template is *not* the problem. In your view, when the form is not valid, all you do is do `return HttpResponse('Login Unsuccessful.')`. So you will *never see* that template with errors displayed. What are you expecting to happen?

Comment: @DanielRoseman Thank you very much. Replaced "return HttpResponse('Form not valid')" with "return render(request, 'signin.html', {'form': form})", which resolved the issue.

Answer (score 0):

```py
    # Validation
    def clean(self):
        cleaned_data = super(UserLoginForm, self).clean()
        username = cleaned_data.get("username")
        email = cleaned_data.get("email")
        email_exist = User.objects.filter(email=email).exists()
        username_exist = User.objects.filter(username=username).exists()

        if username_exist:
            raise forms.ValidationError('User Exists')
        else:
            raise forms.ValidationError('User does not exists')

        return super(UserProfileForm, self).clean()
```

Can you try this?

Comment: Still not throwing forms.ValidationError.

Answer (score 0):

As suggested by @Daniel Roseman,  Replaced "return HttpResponse('Form not valid')" with "return render(request, 'signin.html', {'form': form})", which resolved the issue.